# How would I insert a certain text on my object

Tags: modeling, texturing, text-object

I’m creating a ds lite model and asked my self how I could insert the text on the back (picture 1) on my model?

Would I just retype the text and try to search a similar font or is there a easier way to do the trick? :)

Thanks! [image: Picture 1 - DS lite back]

Comment: use an evenly litphotgraph of the part and use it as a texture of that very part of your model. Use UV-texturing to place it as acurate as you wish.

Comment: take a photo with a correct lighting and in an image app like Photoshop or Krita tweak the luminosity and contrast until you get a b&w image, then use this image as a mask in your material

Comment: Use an image and search for 'using decals in Blender'.

Answer (score 2):

Take a photo with a correct lighting and, in an image app like Photoshop or Krita, tweak the luminosity and contrast until you get a b&w image:

[image]

Then use this image as a mask between 2 colors (grey and black) in order to "print" this image on your object. Here I've set the *Metallic* value to 1 and plugged a *Noise Texture* into the *Roughness* input to get the grainy texture:

[image]

Comment: Thank u so much, that solved my problem <3